# Post/page title to permalink transformation - what is behind the scenes?

Tags: posts, permalinks, pages

If the post name is used as the permalink, what "transformations" does Wordpress do to it when using it as the URL and when does it perform these transformations? Like stropping spaces and special characters, etc.

Thanks for explaining that process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress uses [`sanitize_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title) to create the URL-friendly version of titles for use as post slugs, which has [`sanitize_title_with_dashes`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title_with_dashes) hooked to the `sanitize_title` filter. You can see `sanitize_title` in use [in source for `wp_insert_post` here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3174), and [`sanitize_title_with_dashes` in source here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L1241).